# Nuget package download count using C#

Tags: c#, api, nuget

I'm looking for a way to get the count of nuget package downloads from my C# code. Is it possible? Is any auth required? I see feeds and odata being used for this already but I can't use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A brief look at the API shows that the *overall* index is (for example) `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages`, with each `id` being the URL for a specific package, for example: `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='protobuf-net',Version='2.0.0.668')` which has a `d:DownloadCount` element, where `d` is an xml alias to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices`:

```
<d:DownloadCount m:type="Edm.Int32">73428</d:DownloadCount>
```

So: load the package page, and read the `d:DownloadCount`.

Comment: I will try this, but does it require any authorization like oauth1 or oauth2?

Comment: @nimishashrivastava nope; you can just access it via naked http; no auth required for the public feed

Comment: I got the docs link here- http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NuGet%201.6%20Gallery%20Service%20Endpoints and wanted to get the package stats based on date. Could not find much info. Can you help?

Comment: @nimisha I don't even know if the data you want exists

Comment: Thanks.I checked that too over multiple sources but I do not think it is available via feed api.